# Passing printer inside docker

Tags: usb, docker, udev, printer

I am trying to create a docker image with cups to handle my printer.
When I do this in my docker compose, cups recognizes the printer and I can add it.
On the host:

```
$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 04a9:173a Canon, Inc. PIXMA MP250
```

In the docker-compose.yml:

```
    devices:
      - /dev/bus/usb/001/008:/dev/bus/usb/001/008
```

But when I reconnect the printer with USB, the usb device number sometimes changes. For that, I created an udev rule.

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTRS{idVendor}=="04a9", ATTRS{idProduct}=="173a", MODE="777", SYMLINK+="canon_prixma"
```

Now, when I reconnect the printer, it shows under /dev/canon_prixma. Now, when I try to pass the device inside the docker container, it no longer not get recognized by cups.

```
devices:
- /dev/canon_prixma:/dev/canon_prixma
```

What is the best way to handle this, without using privileged?

Answer (score 1):

It may be the case that [symlinks are not followed when passed in a Docker mount](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38485607/mount-host-directory-with-a-symbolic-link-inside-in-docker-container).

You may want to check it with `sudo docker exec -it your_container ls -la /dev/canon_prixma`.

Probably, the easiest solution would be to share the whole `/dev/` folder or something similar, although it's not the safest option.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It was not clear to me that udev just makes a symlink to /dev/usb/.., but this is the issue, since the symlink can not be resolved inside of docker (logically). But as you said as well, passing all of /dev is not the elegant solution.